# CustomPainter - is shouldRepaint worth the effort?

Tags: flutter

I implemented a CustomPainter. In the shouldRepaint method I have to compare 6 sets for deep equality. I am doing this using setsEqual at the moment.
If they are deeply equal there is no need to repaint, but is it really worth the effort to check that?
Would it be so much worse to just return true and paint even if I wouldn't have to?

Edit:
I forgot to mention that the drawing itselfe is actually pretty simple.
The sets contain objects that calculate points (each about 5) which I then draw as circles.
The color of the circle depends on the set it belongs to. Due to interaction with the user the objects may change to which set they belong,
and if this happens the StatefulWidget holding the CustomPaint gets rebuild using setState.
I think the complex part is to decide whether to repaint: Each set has to be compared with the old delegates set, and if the content of one set has change my CustomPainter should repaint.

Answer (score 3):

CustomPaint can cost *a lot* of power. An example from another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46702376/how-to-ensure-my-custompaint-widget-painting-is-stored-in-the-raster-cache/46706868#46706868) where the user had a huge FPS drop due to constant drawing.

So this is something that can be considered as *worth*.

But the most important thing to be aware of is : `shouldRepaint` is not self sufficient. 
According to the docs :

> It's possible that the paint method will get called even if shouldRepaint returns false (e.g. if an ancestor or descendant needed to be repainted). It's also possible that the paint method will get called without shouldRepaint being called at all (e.g. if the box changes size).

A solution is to use `RepaintBoundary` as explained in the doc, or in the SO question linked above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated the question to make some clarifications :)