# performance issue in drawing using flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using `gestuereDetector` to detect offset and `CustomePaint` to paint the offset in flutter. but after drawing the performance of drawing is becoming slow so please help me to solve this issue.

How can I make it more efficient. My code just follows the below

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _currentPainter = new DrawPainting(_points);

    return new Container(
      child: new ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: new GestureDetector(
          onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
            setState(() {
              RenderBox referenceBox = context.findRenderObject();

              Offset localPosition =
              referenceBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
              _points = new List.from(_points)..add(localPosition);
            });
          },
          onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) =>_points.add(null),
          child: new CustomPaint(
            painter: _currentPainter,

          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


class DrawPainting extends CustomPainter {
  List<Offset> points = [];
  Canvas _lastCanvas;
  Size _lastSize;
  DrawPainting(points){

    this.points = points;
  }

  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    print({"the main paint is called .... ": {"size" : size}});
    _lastCanvas = canvas;
    _lastSize = size;
    Paint paint = new Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 8.0;


    for (int i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
      if (points[i] != null &&
          points[i + 1] != null &&
          (points[i].dx >= 0 &&
              points[i].dy >= 0 &&
              points[i].dx < size.width &&
              points[i].dy < size.height) &&
          (points[i + 1].dx >= 0 &&
              points[i + 1].dy >= 0 &&
              points[i + 1].dx < size.width &&
              points[i + 1].dy < size.height)){
        canvas.drawLine(points[i], points[i + 1], paint);
      }
    }
  }
  bool shouldRepaint(DrawPainting other) => other.points != points;
}
```

Comment: What does "slow" mean exactly? Did you test in debug or release build? Performance tests in debug mode aren't too useful.

Comment: yeah I tested in release mode also while drawing on the screen it paints slowly compare to previous the drawing performance becoming slow when keep on painting on the screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ensure my CustomPaint widget painting is stored in the raster cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46702376/how-to-ensure-my-custompaint-widget-painting-is-stored-in-the-raster-cache)

Comment: I tried with raster cache idea also but performance still decreasing after drawing more points.

Answer (score 3):

The performance issue in drawing app using flutter is resolved by using **drawPath**() and instead of using **setState** for each points to update use **NotifyListener**() to refresh than it will be more efficient than setState.

Comment: What's a `NotifyListener`? I can't find anything with that name on Flutter docs.

Comment: its ChangeNotifier() class which contain NotifyListeners() methode which Call all the registered listeners. use ChangeNotifier as extended class of your custom painter class.

Answer (score 0):

I made a blog on how to make this feature, I hope it helps you.

It describes how to get rid of the weird-looking lines when drawing and also how to implement erase and undo feature as well. Also, setState is not used and a Bloc is used instead.

Blog:
https://ivanstajcer.medium.com/flutter-drawing-erasing-and-undo-with-custompainter-6d00fec2bbc2

Summary: divide all lines into objects and store a Path for each line, as well as a list of Offsets. Then draw the path by calling canvas.drawPath() (this is better than going through all offsets and drawing in between them) and also draw a circle in all of the offsets.

I hope this solves your problem.