# Performance issue in drawing using Path Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am testing the performance in drawing using Flutter. I am using Path to draw line between each point detected by Listener because I have read that the performance would increase using it. I am using Listener because I tried also the Apple Pencil on iPad 2017 by changing the kind property to stylus.

The problem is that I was hoping to get a response in the stroke design similar to notability, it seems much slower, acceptable but not as much as I would like.

So I'm looking for tips to increase performance in terms of speed.

At the following link they recommended using NotifyListener(), but I didn't understand how to proceed. If it really improves performance I would like even an example to be able to implement it.
If Flutter has some limitations when it comes to drawing with your fingers or with a stylus then let me know.
[performance issue in drawing using flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50132188/performance-issue-in-drawing-using-flutter)

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DrawWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DrawWidgetState createState() => _DrawWidgetState();
}

class _DrawWidgetState extends State<DrawWidget> {
  Color selectedColor = Colors.black;
  double strokeWidth = 3.0;
  List<MapEntry<Path, Object>> pathList = List();
  StrokeCap strokeCap = (Platform.isAndroid) ? StrokeCap.butt : StrokeCap.round;
  double opacity = 1.0;

  Paint pa = Paint();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      child: CustomPaint(
        size: Size.infinite,
        painter: DrawingPainter(
          pathList: this.pathList,
        ),
      ),
      onPointerDown: (details) {
        if (details.kind == PointerDeviceKind.touch) {
          print('down');
          setState(() {
            Path p = Path();
            p.moveTo(details.localPosition.dx, details.localPosition.dy);
            pa.strokeCap = strokeCap;
            pa.isAntiAlias = true;
            pa.color = selectedColor.withOpacity(opacity);
            pa.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
            pa.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
            var drawObj = MapEntry<Path,Paint>(p, pa);
            pathList.add(drawObj);
          });
        }
      },
      onPointerMove: (details) {
        if (details.kind == PointerDeviceKind.touch) {
          print('move');
          setState(() {
            pathList.last.key.lineTo(details.localPosition.dx, details.localPosition.dy);
          });
        }
      },
      /*onPointerUp: (details) {
        setState(() {
        });
      },*/
    );
  }
}

class DrawingPainter extends CustomPainter {
  DrawingPainter({this.pathList});
  List<MapEntry<Path, Object>> pathList;
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for(MapEntry<Path, Paint> m in pathList) {
      canvas.drawPath(m.key, m.value);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(DrawingPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use setState, rather use state management like Bloc or ChangeNotifier or smth.

Also, just drawing a path with this:

canvas.drawPath(m.key, m.value);

Works for only small stroke widths, it leaves a weird-looking line full of blank spaces when drawing.

I implemented this by using Bloc that updates the UI based on the gesture functions (onPanStart, onPanEnd, onPanUpdate). It holds a List of a data model that I called CanvasPath that represents one line (so from onPanStart to onPanEnd events), and it holds the resulting Path of that line, list of Offsets and Paint used to paint it.

In the end paint() method draws every single Path from this CanvasPath object and also a circle in every Offset.

`    for every canvasPath do this:

```
      canvas.drawPath(canvasPath.path, _paint);

        for (int i = 0; i < canvasPath.drawPoints.length - 1; i++) {
         
      //draw Circle on every Offset of user interaction
          canvas.drawCircle(
              canvasPath.drawPoints[i],
            _raidus,
              _paint);

        }`
```

I made a blog about this, where it is explained in much more details:
https://ivanstajcer.medium.com/flutter-drawing-erasing-and-undo-with-custompainter-6d00fec2bbc2