# How to perform Expensive Rendering

Tags: dart, flutter

Rendering takes a lot of computational power in many cases. Thus, it can happen that frames are being skipped as the UI needs to wait for the rendering to finish.

I was wondering how I could implement rendering or painting *asynchronously*, i.e. isolated.

Functions like [`compute`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/compute.html) are not an option because [`SendPort`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-isolate/SendPort/send.html) only works with primitive types and painting will require a [`PaintingContext`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/PaintingContext-class.html) or [`Canvas`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas-class.html).

There are Flutter plugins that require heavy rendering. Hence, I thought that I could find answers in the [`video_player`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/video_player) plugin, but it uses [`Texture`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Texture-class.html), i.e. does not render *in Dart*.

I am wondering if there are any idioms or example implementations regarding this.

I you are wondering how I implement rendering, you can take a look at [`FlareActor`](https://github.com/2d-inc/Flare-Flutter/blob/master/flare_flutter/lib/flare_actor.dart). It turns out that they handle painting exactly like I do. Now I am wondering why I am running into bottlenecks and Flare is not. Are there any guides on optimizing painting?

Comment: It’s good question and I want to know about that too. Now I optimize as follows. 1)Limit not to overlap canvases that need repaining. 2)Do not use animation that have multiple frames of image... I guess flutter is not able to optimize preloading multiple frames and calculating overwrapped canvases especially with image. I will read FlareActor’s code! Thanks for your good information!

Comment: Good question, but pretty broad. Can you define what "expensive rendering" is? Because the optimization will definitely depend on what you do. One example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46702376/how-to-ensure-my-custompaint-widget-painting-is-stored-in-the-raster-cache/46706868#46706868

Comment: You can split your slow renderobject into multiple ones. And repaint them partially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by writing all my required pixels to the `BMP` file format and then using `Canvas.drawImage` instead as the Flutter canvas cannot handle many `Canvas` operations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55855735/6509751