# How do I Render Individual Pixels in Flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

#### Setup

I am using a custom [`RenderBox`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/RenderBox-class.html) to draw.
The `canvas` object in the code below comes from the [`PaintingContext` in the `paint` method](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/RenderObject/paint.html).

#### Drawing

I am trying to render *pixels individually* by using [`Canvas.drawRect`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawRect.html).
I should point out that these are sometimes larger and sometimes smaller than the pixels on screen they actually occupy.

```dart
for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
  // in this case the rect size is 1
  canvas.drawRect(
      Rect.fromLTWH(index % (width * height), 
          (index / (width * height)).floor(), 1, 1), Paint()..color = colors[i]);
}
```

#### Storage

I am storing the pixels as a **`List<List<Color>>`** (`colors` in the code above). I tried differently nested lists previously, but they did not cause any noticable discrepancies in terms of performance.
The **memory** on my Android Emulator test device *increases by `282.7MB` when populating the list with a `999x999` image*. Note that it only temporarily increases by `282.7MB`. After about half a minute, the increase drops to `153.6MB` and stays there (without any user interaction).

#### Rendering

With a resolution of `999x999`, the code above causes a **GPU max** of `250.1 ms/frame` and a **UI max** of `1835.9 ms/frame`, which is obviously unacceptable. The UI freezes for two seconds when trying to draw a `999x999` image, which should be a piece of cake (I would guess) considering that 4k video runs smoothly on the same device.

#### CPU

I am not exactly sure how to track this properly using the Android profiler, but while ***populating or changing** the list*, i.e. drawing the pixels (which is the case for the above metrics as well), CPU usage goes from `0%` to up to `60%`. Here are the AVD performance settings:

[image]

#### Cause

I have no idea where to start since I am not even sure *what part* of my code causes the freezing. Is it the memory usage? Or the drawing itself?
How would I go about this in general? What am I doing wrong? How should I store these pixels instead.

#### Efforts

I have tried so much that did not help at all that I will try to only point out the most notable ones:

- I tried converting the `List<List<Color>>` to an [`Image` from the `dart:ui` library](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Image-class.html) hoping to use [`Canvas.drawImage`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawImage.html). In order to do that, I tried encoding my own PNG, but [I have not been able to render more than a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55794346/6509751). However, it did not look like that would boost performance. When trying to convert a `9999x9999` image, I ran into an out of memory exception. Now, I am wondering how video is rendered as all as any 4k video will easily take up more memory than a `9999x9999` image if a few seconds of it are in memory.
- I tried implementing the [`image`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image) package. However, I stopped before completing it as I noticed that it is not meant to be used in Flutter but rather in HTML. I would not have gained anything using that.
- This one is pretty important for the following conclusion I will draw: I tried to ***just draw** without storing the pixels*, i.e. is using `Random.nextInt` to generate random colors. When trying to randomly generate a `999x999` image, this resulted in a **GPU max** of `1824.7 ms/frames` and a **UI max** of `2362.7 ms/frame`, which is even worse, especially in the GPU department.

#### Conclusion

This is the conclusion I reached before trying my failed attempt at rendering using `Canvas.drawImage`: `Canvas.drawRect` is not made for this task as it cannot even draw simple images.

How do you do this in Flutter?

#### Notes

- This is basically [what I **tried** to ask over two months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54736356/6509751) (yes, I have been trying to resolve this issue for that long), but I think that I did not express myself properly back then and that I knew even less what the actual problem was.
- The highest resolution I can properly render is around `10k` pixels. I need at least `1m`.
- I am thinking that abandoning Flutter and going for native might be my only option. However, I would like to believe that I am just approaching this problem completely wrong. I have spent about three months trying to figure this out and I did not find anything that lead me anywhere.

Comment: [instantiateImageCodec](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/instantiateImageCodec.html) says that `BMP` format is supported which is relatively easy to encode from raw ARGB data -  though i have no idea how fast such ARGB->BMP encoding and BMP->Image decoding could be...

Comment: also: how big is your `Layer` tree?

Comment: [   +9 ms]   To hot reload changes while running, press "r". To hot restart (and rebuild state), press "R".
[   +2 ms] An Observatory debugger and profiler on SM T110 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:41854/
[        ] **For a more detailed help message, press "h"**. To detach, press "d"; to quit, press "q".
[+129309 ms] Initializing hot reload...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Solution

`dart:ui` has a function that converts pixels to an `Image` easily: [`decodeImageFromPixels`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/decodeImageFromPixels.html)

- [Example implementation](https://gist.github.com/ds84182/6a949816f860a2344735383afe43e261#file-main-dart)
- [Issue on performance](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31598#issuecomment-511244615)
- [Does not work in the current `master` channel](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36312#issue-468882250)

I was simply not aware of this back when I created this answer, which is why I wrote the "**Alternative**" section.

## Alternative

Thanks to [@pslink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) for reminding me of `BMP` after I wrote that I had failed to encode my own `PNG`.
I had looked into it previously, but I thought that it looked to complicated without sufficient documentation. Now, I found [this nice article](http://www.dragonwins.com/domains/GetTechEd/bmp/bmpfileformat.htm) explaining the necessary `BMP` headers and implemented **32-bit BGRA (ARGB but BGRA is the order of the default mask)** by copying [Example 2 from the "BMP file format" Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Example_2). I went through all sources but could not find an original source for this example. Maybe the authors of the Wikipedia article wrote it themselves.

### Results

Using `Canvas.drawImage` and my `999x999` pixels converted to an image from a `BMP` byte list, I get a **GPU max** of `9.9 ms/frame` and a **UI max** of `7.1 ms/frame`, *which is awesome*!

```dart
|  ms/frame |  Before (Canvas.drawRect) | After (Canvas.drawImage) |
|-----------|---------------------------|--------------------------|
|  GPU max  | 1824.7                    | 9.9                      |
|  UI max   | 2362.7                    | 7.1                      |
```

### Conclusion

Canvas operations like `Canvas.drawRect` are not meant to be used like that.

### Instructions

First of, this is quite straight-forward, however, you need to correctly populate the byte list, otherwise, you are going to get an error that your data is not correctly formatted and see no results, which can be quite frustrating.

You will need to *prepare your image **before drawing*** as you cannot use `async` operations in the paint call.

In code, you need to use a [`Codec`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Codec-class.html) to transform your list of bytes into an image.

```dart
final list = [
            0x42, 0x4d, // 'B', 'M'
            ...];
// make sure that you either know the file size, data size and data offset beforehand
//        or that you edit these bytes afterwards

final Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(list);

final Codec codec = await instantiateImageCodec(bytes));

final Image image = (await codec.getNextFrame()).image;
```

You need to pass this image to your drawing widget, e.g. using a [`FutureBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).
Now, you can just use [`Canvas.drawImage`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawImage.html) in your draw call.

Comment: aah, I used it before many times but didn't see any numbers (just charts) - now I see the numbers too, thanks a lot, btw if you want to get max available performance you could take a look into [examples/layers/raw/spinning_square.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/layers/raw/spinning_square.dart) or any other source in that folder