# Can Flutter render images from raw pixel data?

Tags: flutter, rendering

I had an idea for a library that provides widgets of various rendered visual effects (think the "Clouds" effect from Photoshop) and I've run into a roadblock. Every method to render raw pixel data is either prohibitively slow (`drawRect`, `drawRawPoints`, etc.) or requires the use of Futures that makes realtime effects unfeasible (`decodeImageFromPixels`, [Generate a BMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55844043/how-do-i-render-individual-pixels-in-flutter), etc.).

I'm looking for a way to synchronously generate a rendered bitmap effect in realtime. I would think that it should be possible (it's possible in Skia, anyway), but I can't find anything in the documentation to suggest how to do it nor can I think of an existing widget that would make use of it.

Comment: Btw, the gist of my question from back then is basically that it is not possible and thus [this issue was created](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37180#issue-474139918) - I know that this is from shortly after you posted your question, but the discussion was already ongoing for months at that time.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I remember, I posted a lot on that issue. (I posted the linked proposal, in fact.)