# How to tell flutter widget that keyboard doesnt change screen size

Tags: flutter, dart, calculation, statelesswidget

I was looking for a way to split my background in my flutter application using a wave, and I found this piece of code:
[Design a background from 2 images in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57362018/design-a-background-from-2-images-in-flutter/57466888#57466888)

It works perfectly, and I could adapt it to my needs. The only thing I don't understand is that every time I open my keyboard and type something into an input field, the wave is recalculated. I thought if I used a StatelessWidget, that wouldn't happen. Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: try setting `resizeToAvoidBottomInsets` on the `Scaffold` to false and see if it works

Comment: @LoVe Unfortunately this does not work. I set it in the Scaffold of the "Background" as wall as in the Scaffold of the View where I use it. Btw. Both of those are StatelessWidgets. Do you have another idea how I could solve this problem?