# Optimize zoomable grid with more than 400 small boxes

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have created something like calendar with clickable boxes but because the boxes are many the performance on Android is bad (no such problems on iOS).
I am using the following code to render the whole thing:

```
ClipRect(
                          child: PhotoView.customChild(
                              customSize: Size(gridWidth, constraints.maxHeight),
                              child: GridView.builder(
                                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                    crossAxisCount: 13,
                                    mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                                    crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                                    childAspectRatio: 1),
                                itemCount: gridCreationHelperClass.boxWidgets.length,
                                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  return gridCreationHelperClass.boxWidgets[index];
                                },
                              ),
                              minScale: 1.0,
                              //initialScale: 5.0,
                              backgroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.transparent),
                              childSize: Size(gridWidth, constraints.maxHeight),
                              scaleChange: gridCreationHelperClass.scaleHasChanged,
                        )
```

These boxWidgets can be either a Container:

```
Container(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
        color: color,
        child: Text(showTextInBox ? text : "", style: TextStyle(fontSize: textInBoxSize,color: Colors.white,
            fontFamily: getFontStatic(complexFont)), textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
```

or a SVG:

```
Stack(children: <Widget>[
      new SvgPicture.asset(
        "images/squ.svg",
        color: color,

      ),
      Text(showTextInBox ? text : "", style: TextStyle(fontSize: textInBoxSize,color: Colors.white,
          fontFamily: getFontStatic(complexFont)), textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
    ],alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center)
```

Also when zooming in text is added to see the date more easily.

Do you have idea how to make it all faster?
I was thinking about making a CustomPainter but how do I go with it and will it even make things faster?

Screenshots:

[image: Main Image]

[image: Zoomed in Container]

[image: Zoomed in SVG]

I am using these libraries:

```
//fork of
photo_view: ^0.4.0
flutter_svg: 0.13.0+1
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Never used the photo_view library, but pretty sure you have to cache somehow the views.

Check this post about optimizing the drawing... it might work:

[How to ensure my CustomPaint widget painting is stored in the raster cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46702376/how-to-ensure-my-custompaint-widget-painting-is-stored-in-the-raster-cache/46706868)

Answer (score 1):

Well it was problematic only on my OnePlus 5T, it runs very smoothly (with Containers only, not SVGs) on any other android phone even my 50$ chinese test phone and the my original Sony Xperia Z on Android Jelly Bean.
OnePlus is just weird I guess.

Also currently I am ditching the whole GridView and building a CustomPainter and it is solid 60 fps with zooming and scrolling even on Debug on my OP 5T + CustomPainter gives me quite a lot of freedom and I don't have to worry about future flutter changes.

Answer (score 0):

So I've taken a different approach that seems performant so far. There's no real need to use the external PhotoView dependency for this purpose at all. Better to just add a `double _scale;` to your state and then use Flutter's built-in `GestureDetector`:

```
GestureDetector(
  onScaleUpdate: (ScaleUpdateDetails scaleDetails) {
    setState(() {
      _scale = scaleDetails.horizontalScale;
    });
  },
  child: GridView.builder(
    gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: max(1, (16 / _scale).floor())),
    itemCount: _counter * 17,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return GridTile(
          child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/image.svg'));
    },
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
  ),
),
```

Looking at the [PhotoView docs](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view) it seems really oriented towards zoomable/pannable photos - not really what you want for a grid layout like this anyway. If the above isn't exactly what you want, you can probably make it what you want by putting some `Container`s around the `GridView` and using your state appropriately.